# Jquery nav tab little change

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need change this Function

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".tab_content").hide();
    $("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show();
    $(".tab_content:first").show();

    $("ul.tabs li").click(function () {
        $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $(".tab_content").hide();
        var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
        $(activeTab).fadeIn();
        return false;
    });
});
```

to work like:

if **click** and **activeTab** == "**#a**" load information from some file, like

```
$('#a').load('a.php?'+ Math.random());
```

if **click** and **activeTab** == "**#b**" load information from

```
$('#b').load('b.php?'+ Math.random());
```

i tried but not work to me, [here is the example on JSFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/zve79pk9/)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get a load error when I do this, so it would probably work if the page actually exists.

```
$(activeTab).fadeIn(300, function(){
    $(this).load($(this).attr("id")+".php?"+Math.random());
});
```

Comment: this is very nice, but if for example my files names not like attr("id"), can you give me more help with this. And thanks for that, without check i see it will work.

Comment: Well you have to provide the info. What you had worked with the ID. You could add a custom tag, you could also add a hidden input in the div, it really depends on what it is you are doing.

Comment: I will stay with this (Like your code) :-) Tnx again!